# How to get most nearest result?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a problem on getting the nearest result on javascript.

Example:

I want to get the minimum value which is most satisfied.
The value I want is 3, but the result is much higher.

```
const goalValue = 3;
const data = [{ name: 'A', minimum: 1}, { name: 'A', minimum: 2}, { name: 'A', minimum: 5} ];
    
const result = data.find(item => item.name === 'A' && item.minimum >= goalValue);
```

result is

> `{ name: 'A', val: 5 }`

it should the nearest which is the

> `{ name: 'A', val: 2 }`

Comment: https://codeburst.io/javascript-finding-minimum-and-maximum-values-in-an-array-of-objects-329c5c7e22a2

Comment: `const result = data.reduce((prev, curr) => ( (Math.abs(curr.minimum - goalValue) < Math.abs(prev.minimum - goalValue) ? curr : prev) ));`

Comment: @Jayce444 This is working when the `goalValue` is 3, but when we change it to 4, the  result is `{ name: 'A', val: 5 }`

Comment: @bossajie yes...which is correct? 5 is closest to 4. It gets the object with the value *closest* to the goal value

Comment: @Jayce444 nope, since the goal value `4`, the goal value is not equal to the 5 or more than, there is still the 2 which is the minimum.

Comment: @bossajie Ohhh when you say "minimum" you literally mean the smallest one? I thought you were referring to the key name you use in your object lol. Kind of confusing. Ok try this: `const result = data.reduce((prev, curr) => ( goalValue > curr.minimum ? curr : prev) );` I think that's what you mean. If you want it to match when they're equal, you can just change it to `>=`

Comment: @Jaycee444 Worked like magic! Thank you so much, sorry for the confusion of my question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there's a more efficient way but this is what I'd do:

1. Map your data to contain the subtraction of `val` and `goalValue`
2. Sort the resulting array by the newly creating attribute of each object
3. The first value should be the closest
   (Closest meaning the `mininum` value is numerically close to your goalValue, so applying this to `[29, 99, 1, 100]` with a goalValue of `30` should result in 29)

Example:

```js
const goalValue = 3;
const data = [{ name: 'A', minimum: 1}, { name: 'A', minimum: 2}, { name: 'A', minimum: 5} ];
   
const goalData = data.map(d => ({...d, sortingValue: Math.abs(d.minimum - goalValue)}))
const [closest] = goalData.sort((a, b) => a.sortingValue - b.sortingValue > 0 ? 1: -1)

// Clean up the data structure
const closestTransformed = {
  val: closest.minimum,
  name: closest.name
}
console.log(closestTransformed)
```

To conclude: You have to look at multiple values, you can't just take the first one that's bigger or smaller because you never know if the next one is closer.

Answer (score 2):

All you need is to declare a variable at first with the max safe number
after that iterate through all elements and check which one has the minimum absolute difference

```js
const goalValue = 3;
const data = [{ name: 'A', minimum: 1}, { name: 'A', minimum: 2}, { name: 'A', minimum: 5} ];

let minDifference = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
let elIndex;

data.forEach((el, index) => {
  let diff = Math.abs(el.minimum - goalValue);
  if(diff < minDifference){
    minDifference = diff;
    elIndex = index;
  }
})

console.log(data[elIndex]);
```

you could read more about **MAX_SAFE_INTEGER** [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)